# Finding the largest values in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table`:

```
> x <- data.table(neighborhood = c("a", "b", "c"), cat1 = c(1, 1, 100), cat2 = c(50, 1, 1), cat3 = c(1, 1, 1))
> x
   neighborhood cat1 cat2 cat3
1:            a    1   50    1
2:            b    1    1    1
3:            c  100    1    1
>
```

I'd like to find large values (eg) `>= 50`.

I don't have a specific way I'd like to see this (this is for output), but this would work:

```
> z
   neighborhood category value
1:            a     cat1    50
2:            c     cat2   100
```

I've been wracking my brain, but I can't think of a function for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: `melt` and then subset as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `melt()`

```
melt(x, "neighborhood")[value >= 50, .SD, keyby = neighborhood]
#    neighborhood variable value
# 1:            a     cat2    50
# 2:            c     cat1   100
```

Or if you're not concerned with order you can use

```
melt(x, "neighborhood")[value >= 50]
#    neighborhood variable value
# 1:            c     cat1   100
# 2:            a     cat2    50
```